# How one pthread waits for another to finish via futex in linux?

Tags: linux, pthreads, glibc, musl, futex

I want to create thread via linux `clone()` and and wait for it to finish. Such a seemingly simple case has become difficult for me because I don’t know how to wait in the calling thread for the end of the called. Linux `wait()` does not work for threads, just for processes. I started studying how the pthread library is implemented in various libc implementations.

For example, I have a little program with `pthread_join()` call:

```
void* waited_foo(void* p)
{
    sleep(1);  //EDIT
    printf("1111\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* agrv[])
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    if (pthread_create(&tid, &attr, &waited_foo, NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
    }

    pthread_join(tid,NULL);
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

I trace all the syscalls via `strace`:

```
strace -f -e trace=\!brk,mmap,mprotect,munmap,rt_sigprocmask ./a.out
```

On alpine linux with musl libc:

```
clone(child_stack=0x7f9f63666af8, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|0x400000strace: Process 163 attached
, parent_tid=[163], tls=0x7f9f63666b38, child_tidptr=0x7f9f636fdf90) = 163
[pid   163] nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid   162] futex(0x7f9f63666b70, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid   163] <... nanosleep resumed>0x7f9f63666aa0) = 0
[pid   163] ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=39, ws_col=231, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
[pid   163] writev(1, [{iov_base="1111", iov_len=4}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 21111) = 5
[pid   163] futex(0x7f9f63666b70, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid   162] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid   163] <... futex resumed>)        = 1
[pid   162] futex(0x7f9f636fdf90, FUTEX_WAIT, 163, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid   163] exit(0)                     = ?
[pid   162] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid   163] +++ exited with 0 +++
nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff336faca0) = 0
```

On debian linux with GNU libc:

```
clone(child_stack=0x7f4859865e30, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f48598669d0, tls=0x7f4859866700, child_tidptr=0x7f48598669d0) = 11383
futex(0x7f48598669d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 11383, NULLstrace: Process 11383 attached
 <unfinished ...>
[pid 11383] set_robust_list(0x7f48598669e0, 24) = 0
[pid 11383] nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7f4859865d50) = 0
[pid 11383] write(1, "1111\n", 51111)       = 5
[pid 11383] madvise(0x7f4859066000, 8368128, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
[pid 11383] exit(0)                     = ?
[pid 11383] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... futex resumed> )                   = 0
nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7ffd9d9d3460) = 0
```

And now I really don't understand:

1. why in musl need 2 futex wait?
2. why on glibc used 1 futex_wait without futex_wake? what the magic?)
3. why futex_wait use pid of new thread?

Comment: "I want to create thread via linux clone() and and wait for it to finish" -- note that you can't call _any_ `libc` functions in that `clone`d thread. You _probably_ don't actually want to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Linux, the `futex()` system call is a sort of swiss army knife as it is able to accomplish various actions. In the context of the *pthread* library, it is used in conjunction with `clone()` system call.

### Behavior in Linux/GLIBC

The below explanation is based on the following `strace` output when using the GNU C library:

```
clone(child_stack=0x7f4859865e30, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f48598669d0, tls=0x7f4859866700, child_tidptr=0x7f48598669d0) = 11383
futex(0x7f48598669d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 11383, NULLstrace: Process 11383 attached
 <unfinished ...>
[pid 11383] set_robust_list(0x7f48598669e0, 24) = 0
[pid 11383] nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7f4859865d50) = 0
[pid 11383] write(1, "1111\n", 51111)       = 5
[pid 11383] madvise(0x7f4859066000, 8368128, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
[pid 11383] exit(0)                     = ?
[pid 11383] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... futex resumed> )                   = 0
nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7ffd9d9d3460) = 0
```

In the GLIBC, `pthread_create()` calls `clone()` to which are passed the following flags: **CLONE_VM**|**CLONE_FS**|**CLONE_FILES**|**CLONE_SIGHAND**|**CLONE_THREAD**|**CLONE_SYSVSEM**|**CLONE_SETTLS**|**CLONE_PARENT_SETTID**|**CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID**. The latter two flags are the ones to focus on to answer the question.

The [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) presents **CLONE_PARENT_SETTID** as:

> Store the child thread ID at the location pointed to by parent_tid [...] The store operation completes before the clone call returns control to user space.

In the `strace` output example, the identifier of the newly created thread is stored at *parent_tidptr=0x7f48598669d0*.

The [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) presents **CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID**)  as:

> Clear (zero) the child thread ID at the location pointed
> to by child_tid [...] in child memory when the child exits,
> and do a wakeup on the futex at that address.

In other words, the kernel will atomically reset the memory area pointed by the parameter *child_tidptr=0x7f48598669d0* and call `futex()` with the **FUTEX_WAKE** operation (meaning of "and do a wakeup on the futex" in the manual).

We can notice that both flags refer to the same address *0x7f48598669d0* into which the thread identifier is stored a creation time and will be reset at thread exit time.

`pthread_join()` relies on this mechanism to wait for the end of the thread. It calls `futex()` with the **FUTEX_WAIT** operation. The [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) presents it as:

> This operation tests that the value at the futex word
> pointed to by the address uaddr still contains the
> expected value val, and if so, then sleeps waiting for a
> FUTEX_WAKE operation on the futex word.

So, it checks that the memory area pointed by the 1st parameter *uaddr* contains the value specified by the 3rd parameter *val*. In your example, it checks that the value 11383 is at address 0x7f48598669d0. As long as the memory area contains this value, the caller is suspended. The value 11383 is nothing else than the thread identifier (at kernel level) returned by clone. And the address 0x7f48598669d0 is the one passed to `clone()` that will be reset by the kernel and for which a **FUTEX_WAKE** operation will be done when the thread is finished.

That is why `strace` output shows the *resume* of the **FUTEX_WAIT** operation right after the termination (exit) of the thread. The **FUTEX_WAKE** operation has been invoked by the kernel as specified by the **CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID** flag passed to `clone()`.

### Behavior in Linux/MUSL

The below explanation is based on the following `strace` output when using the MUSL C library:

```
clone(child_stack=0x7f9f63666af8, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|0x400000strace: Process 163 attached
, parent_tid=[163], tls=0x7f9f63666b38, child_tidptr=0x7f9f636fdf90) = 163
[pid   163] nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid   162] futex(0x7f9f63666b70, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid   163] <... nanosleep resumed>0x7f9f63666aa0) = 0
[pid   163] ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=39, ws_col=231, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
[pid   163] writev(1, [{iov_base="1111", iov_len=4}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 21111) = 5
[pid   163] futex(0x7f9f63666b70, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid   162] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid   163] <... futex resumed>)        = 1
[pid   162] futex(0x7f9f636fdf90, FUTEX_WAIT, 163, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid   163] exit(0)                     = ?
[pid   162] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid   163] +++ exited with 0 +++
nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff336faca0) = 0
```

In the [source code](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/snapshot/musl-1.2.3.tar.gz), the following set of flags are passed to `clone()` by `pthread_create()`: **CLONE_VM**|**CLONE_FS**|**CLONE_FILES**|**CLONE_SIGHAND**|**CLONE_THREAD**|**CLONE_SYSVSEM**|**CLONE_SETTLS**|**CLONE_PARENT_SETTID**|**CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID**|**CLONE_DETACHED**. Compared to GLIBC, there is an additional flag: **CLONE_DETACH**. But according to the manual, this flag is deprecated by **CLONE_THREAD**.

A creation time, the *detach_state* field in the thread's descriptor is set to **DT_JOINABLE** (this is the default when nothing else is specified in the creation attributes passed to `pthread_create()`). The value of the latter constant is **2** as defined in the *internal/pthread_impl.h* file:

```c
enum {
    DT_EXITED = 0,
    DT_EXITING,
    DT_JOINABLE,
    DT_DETACHED,
};
```

The thread entry function passed to `clone()` is defined in *src/thread/pthread_create.c* as:

```c
static int start(void *p)
{
[...]
    __pthread_exit(args->start_func(args->start_arg));
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code snippet, the entry point specified by the user is called through `args->start_func(args->start_arg)` and its result is passed to the internal `__pthread_exit()`. This is the place where the *detach_state* field of the thread's descriptor is first reset to 0 (value of **DT_EXITED**) for which `futex()` is called with the **FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE** operation and the count value equal to **1** to wake up one waiting thread:

```c
_Noreturn void __pthread_exit(void *result)
{
[...]
    /* Wake any joiner. */
    a_store(&self->detach_state, DT_EXITED);
    __wake(&self->detach_state, 1, 1);
[...]
    for (;;) __syscall(SYS_exit, 0);
}
```

In the above code snippet, the internal `__wake()` function hides the call to `futex()` with the **FUTEX_WAKE(_PRIVATE)** operation:

```c
static inline void __wake(volatile void *addr, int cnt, int priv)
{
    if (priv) priv = FUTEX_PRIVATE;
    if (cnt<0) cnt = INT_MAX;
    __syscall(SYS_futex, addr, FUTEX_WAKE|priv, cnt) != -ENOSYS ||
    __syscall(SYS_futex, addr, FUTEX_WAKE, cnt);
}
```

The service `pthread_join()` defined in *src/thread/pthread_join.c* calls `futex()` with the **FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE** operation and the current value of the field *detach_state* in the thread descriptor. That is to say **2** as this field is set to **DT_JOINABLE** at thread creation time:

```c
static int __pthread_timedjoin_np(pthread_t t, void **res, const struct timespec *at)
{
[...]
    while ((state = t->detach_state) && r != ETIMEDOUT && r != EINVAL) {
        if (state >= DT_DETACHED) a_crash();
        r = __timedwait_cp(&t->detach_state, state, CLOCK_REALTIME, at, 1);
    }
[...]
    return 0;
}
```

The call to `futex()` is done by *__timedwait_cp()* defined in _thread/_*timedwait.c*:

```c
int __timedwait_cp(volatile int *addr, int val,
    clockid_t clk, const struct timespec *at, int priv)
{
    int r;
    struct timespec to, *top=0;

    if (priv) priv = FUTEX_PRIVATE;

    if (at) {
        if (at->tv_nsec >= 1000000000UL) return EINVAL;
        if (__clock_gettime(clk, &to)) return EINVAL;
        to.tv_sec = at->tv_sec - to.tv_sec;
        if ((to.tv_nsec = at->tv_nsec - to.tv_nsec) < 0) {
            to.tv_sec--;
            to.tv_nsec += 1000000000;
        }
        if (to.tv_sec < 0) return ETIMEDOUT;
        top = &to;
    }

    r = -__futex4_cp(addr, FUTEX_WAIT|priv, val, top);
    if (r != EINTR && r != ETIMEDOUT && r != ECANCELED) r = 0;
    /* Mitigate bug in old kernels wrongly reporting EINTR for non-
     * interrupting (SA_RESTART) signal handlers. This is only practical
     * when NO interrupting signal handlers have been installed, and
     * works by sigaction tracking whether that's the case. */
    if (r == EINTR && !__eintr_valid_flag) r = 0;

    return r;
}
```

To sum up, on the newly created thread side, the field *detach_state* of the thread's descriptor is first set to **2** (**DT_JOINABLE**) by the caller of `pthread_create()`. Once the entry point returns, the field  is set to **0** (**DT_EXITED**) by the thread and it calls `futex()` with the **FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE** operation and the value **1** to wake up one waiting thread on this field.
With `pthread_join()`, a call to `futex()` with the **FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE** operation is done to wait as long as the *detach_state* field is equal to **2** (**DT_JOINABLE**). So, the service returns once the thread sets the field to **0** and calls **FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE**.

### Conclusion

As opposed to GLIBC, MUSL doesn't rely on the **CLONE_PARENT_SETTID** and **CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID** flags to manage the join operation of the threads.

So, why the GLIBC is using **FUTEX_WAIT** instead of **FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE** as we are inside a process with shared memory between threads. I guess there are two reasons:

1. The **PRIVATE** version of the futexes [arrived later](https://lwn.net/Articles/229668/);
2. The **CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID** flag of `clone()` is for general purposes: it may not concern only inter-thread synchronization. This could be used for inter-process synchronization. So, the kernel uses **FUTEX_WAKE**.

Comment: thank you very much! 
But According to documentation and you answer, we need just 1 futex_wait. Why musl call extra futex_wait/futex_wake for 1 and 2 values?

Comment: For musl you didn't trace the same code as even the thread is calling nanosleep()

Comment: in code block I forgot to add sleep(1) in waited_foo. strace output is given for code with timeout. Edit question
But dont understand with extra futex calls

Comment: I looked at the source code of musl and added the explanation in the answer.

Comment: omg, really thank you...
but why in futex pass wait/wake instead waik_private/wake_private for thread(not process!) synchronization?

Comment: @xperious: I added a possible answer to this question in the conclusion of the answer.